# How can I be sure I have downloaded all data from a WFS service?

Tags: python, geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I need to download all data from a WFS service as CSV files and be sure I've downloaded all data.

I'm using Python to download chunks of 20 000 rows at a time:

```
import urllib.request
import os

download_folder = r'C:\Arenden\arter_test'

for start in range(0, 1000000, 20000): #I'm using 1000000 as stop since I dont know the row count of the service
    #For each 20 000 chunk create the url string
    req = "https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences&maxFeatures=20000&startIndex={0}&outputFormat=csv".format(start)
    print(req)
    
    #And save the csv file
    file = os.path.join(download_folder, "allswedishoccurrences_{0}.csv".format(start))
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(req, file)
```

Is there a way of knowing when to stop? It just keeps going

```
https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences&count=20000&startIndex=0&outputFormat=csv
https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences&count=20000&startIndex=20000&outputFormat=csv
...
```

[image]

There are no duplicates in the csv files:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'/home/bera/GIS/wrk/Species/csvfiles/allswedishoccurrences_20000-40000.csv')
#df1.shape
#(20000, 78)

df2 = pd.read_csv(r'/home/bera/GIS/wrk/Species/csvfiles/allswedishoccurrences_40000-60000.csv')
#df2.shape
#(20000, 78)

#df1.equals(df2)
#False

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
#df3.shape
#(40000, 78)

df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
#df3.shape
#(40000, 78)
```

Comment: Ask for the count before you start, request=hits

Comment: How? `https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences&resultType:hits` ?

Comment: Yes, but with an "=" instead of  ":", https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences&resultType=hits

Comment: count and startindex aren't parameters for a WFS version 1.1.n GetFeature request; there is only maxfeatures

Comment: But GeoServer supports paging with `startindex` and `maxfeatures` with WFS 1.1.0 as a vendor specific extra.

Comment: GeoServer docs claim that `startindex` and `count` are supported also with WFS 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html but `count` does not work for me while `maxFeatures` does. That combination works also with WMS https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html

Comment: I realize now that count does not seem to work for me either, each csv file contains 25000 rows, and not 20000

Comment: But do you get (partly) different data with your varying startIndex values? If you manage somehow to get more than 25000 unique features then the configuration at the agricultural university is wrong. The WFS 2.0.0 query with resulttype=hits is supposed to return the true count of the whole feature type in numberMatched.

Comment: They are completely different. See the edit of the wfs request and the identical check. I'll just keep it downloading until the csv file sizes get <10 kB. But it is no good, the service might go offline and stop the downloading and will not know

Comment: I recommend to contact SLU and ask about their data. You can find an email address from https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=getcapabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using `https://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SLW/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SLW:AllSwedishOccurrences&resultType=hits` gives me:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="25000" timeStamp="2022-05-03T12:00:14.842Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd http://www.svenskalifewatch.se/ http://slwgeo.artdata.slu.se:8080/geoserver/SLW/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=SLW%3AAllSwedishOccurrences">
<gml:featureMembers>
```

so there are 25000 features in that collection.

Comment: I dont think this is working like I want it to. I just created a wfs service with 25 polygons in it and got 25 back with `hits`. Then I set https://imgur.com/a/k6HG1Fx to 5, tried again and  got 5 back with `hits`. But I am still able to download all 25 as csv if I do it 5 at a time. Maybe it is not possible to always show the total count

Comment: Right, verified with GeoServer 2.20.3 by setting the page size into 10. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&typename=topp:states&request=GetFeature&resulttype=hits returns `wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="10"`. That's not the total count of states. WFS 2.0 returns NumberMatched that is correct.

Comment: The Swedish server does returns numberMatched="25000" with WFS 2.0. It may be right even so exact number feels a bit suspicious.

Comment: as I recall it's only really supported for WFS 2.0

Comment: Yes, obviously they observed that the numberOfFeatures was not good for this use case. Because WFS 1.1.x does not officially support paging and there may be a server side limit for maxFeatures user can get the whole feature type only by making  a bunch of request with spatial or attribute filters which each return less data than maxFeatures.