# Downloading multiple data from multiple WFS addresses

Tags: qgis, wfs

I have a problem with downloading data from the WFS. I have about a thousand WFS addresses that I need to download in a short period of time and would like to speed this up.

Do you know of any ways to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Gnu parallel could do it but you are likely bandwidth limited

Comment: I've tried the loop, but I don't know python enough to make something out of it.

Comment: Have done this to a limit - but it's either your internet or the servers bandwidth connection that will timeout.

Comment: How are you doing it now, what is the limiting factor?
 [This is an example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430291/how-can-i-be-sure-i-have-downloaded-all-data-from-a-wfs-service) for one service using urllib.request